# meteor cannot observe queries with skip or limit

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am probably missing something quite obvious or missing something in the documentation.  I searched and did not find similar question.  posting it.

Both of these

```
return Items.find({},{sort: {time: -1}, limit: 10});
```

or

```
return Items.find({},{sort: {time: -1}).limit(10);
```

result in `meteor cannot observe queries with skip or limit`

Comment: Issue has been registered.  Check out this [github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/528#issuecomment-11229625)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE: This is longer an issue.  Beginning with Meteor 0.5.3, you can observe queries with `skip` and `limit` options.**

Unfortunately, this is true: the mimimongo package doesn't currently support calling `observe` on cursors that used the `skip` or `limit` options.  There's no good reason for this; it's just not implemented.

If you're calling this query inside a template helper, there's an easy workaround:

```
Template.name.items = function () {
  // fetch array of all the items
  var items = Items.find({}, {sort: {time: -1}}).fetch();

  // return only the first 10 items to the template
  return items.slice(0,10);
};
```

The downside of the workaround is efficiency.  If your helper returns a cursor (just returning the value of `Items.find` without calling `fetch`, then the template system is smart enough not to recalculate the whole template when just one item changes, or if a new item is inserted.

On the other hand, calling `fetch` in the helper registers a dependency on the *entire* query result, so the whole template gets recalculated any time any object in the query changes.

There's no other difference.  The template will put the same thing on the screen and it will preserve the contents of form elements when it has to redraw itself.

Comment: thank you, that worked.  does the road map consider a another mongodb package to avoid the confusion between the mongodb docs and such.

Comment: We'd like minimongo to implement the full MongoDB API.  Patches welcome.  http://docs.meteor.com/#collections has a list of missing items.

Comment: The documentation on [link](http://docs.meteor.com/#data) shows limits and may need to be updated? `Template.players.top_10_scorers = function () {
  return Users.find({}, {sort: {score: -1}, limit: 10});
};`   i wish i could help but i am a greener newb and just learning this stuff

Comment: Yikes, that's a bug, will be fixed next release.

Comment: Any timeframe for when skip and limit might be implemented?  These seem crucial for implementing efficient pagination.  Otherwise all skip/limit operations have to be performed in the server and the local cache updated in real-time to reflect only what should be displayed (and no more) rather than pre-fetching and caching results on the client.

Comment: This is now fixed on the devel branch, and will in the next release of Meteor.

Comment: What doesn't work still is Collection.count() but Collection.find().count() works. I would like to see more things that work in the mongo shell work in meteor and follow the same syntax as it matures.