# Meteor: Uncaught Error: must use ordered observe with skip or limit

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this error on Meteor 0.7.1.2 while according to this post:
[meteor cannot observe queries with skip or limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157454/meteor-cannot-observe-queries-with-skip-or-limit),
the problem has been fixed 2 years ago.

Example:

```
var mon = Mon.find({}, {sort: {utctime: -1}, limit: 50})
mon.observe({
    added: console.log("Document added to the Mon collection")
})
```

I can't figure out a solution to this. What is an ordered observe?

Comment: Might be a [bug in Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1643).

Comment: You used console.log in place of a function in your observer, I'm not sure this can work. Also is this on the client or server?

Comment: If I remove the sort and limit, events are being catched, so console log is not the problem. However, I omitted somthing that might cause problem: Here is my Collection definition:

Comment: Hmm.. You didn't post your collection details. But I suspect you are gathering it from DDP from another server? If you are doing this then it is a known bug that you cant observe data from collections declared this way